# Starter guide for git/github?

Tags: git, github

I'm a novice when it comes to version control. Git looks pretty neat, and I've seen some interesting projects on github ([Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) in particular). I've set up git and github, and I've looked up a tutorial or two, but I can't quite get my head around the whole workflow I should be building around using git.

What's the best way to get started with git/github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn to use git first and foremost. If you don't understand Git, GitHub won't do much of anything for you in terms of actually doing development or working with other developers.

Despite the name, I've actually found [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/) to be a great book to read through. Doesn't hurt that it's completely free to read, and you can buy the paperback if you'd like a tangible copy or want to show your support.

AFTER you understand Git, [GitHub Help](http://help.github.com/) is a great launching point to glue together Git use and GitHub storage/everyday use.

Answer (score 2):

I found [Everyday GIT With 20 Commands Or So](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/everyday.html) to be a good start, for github work see the two Individual Developer sections. Just git clone the github path for the project

Answer (score 1):

I started with GitMagic from git://github.com/blynn/gitmagic.git. (Actually, I used the Ubuntu packaged version.

Comment: I'm having trouble compiling that, maybe I'll just try reading the online version.

Answer (score 0):

A simple tutorial is integrated in git: `man gitutorial` and `man gittutorial-2` will give you something to start with.